# Angularjs scope variable after $http call isn't updated in the view

Tags: scope, angularjs, digest

I have this in the service:

```
UpdateQuestionsSmsStatus: function (smsProfileId, active) {
    //TODO: ajax get data
    var promise = this.UpdateQuestionsSmsStatusInternal(smsProfileId, active).then(function (response) {
        // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
        return response;
    });
    // Return the promise to the controller
    return promise;
},

UpdateQuestionsSmsStatusInternal: function (smsProfileId, active) {

    return $http({ method: 'GET',
        url: '../QuestionManagement/UpdateQuestionsSmsStatus?smsProfileId=' + smsProfileId + '&active=' + active
    }).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          // this callback will be called asynchronously
          // when the response is available
          response = data;
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
          if (window.console && console.log) {
              console.log("Could not obtain questions received. Error:" + data + "Status:" + status + "Headers:" + headers + "Config:" + config);
          }
      });
},
```

This in my controller:

```
$scope.updateQuestionsSmsStatus = function () {
    questionSelectionService.UpdateQuestionsSmsStatus($scope.smsProfile.Id, !$scope.smsProfile.Active).then(function (output) {
        $scope.smsProfile.Active = (output.data.result == "success") ? output.data.active : !output.data.active;
    });

};
```

Which is called onclick from the view.
And this in the view:

```
{{smsProfile.Active}}
```

The value in the view is never updated. Debugger doesn't show anything wrong, no errors appear.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Does the debugger see the data coming all the way back to the controller? eg, is output.data populated in your last promise?

Comment: is it using onclick or ng-click?  If it's the former then you should wrap the onclick callback in a $scope.$apply.  If it's the latter then something else is up, since ng-click wraps it in an $apply for you.

Comment: @RoyTruelove ng-click="updateQuestionsSmsStatus()"

Answer (score 1):

Your success callback in `UpdateQuestionsSmsStatusInternal`function needs to return a value:

```
return $http({ method: 'GET',
        url: '../QuestionManagement/UpdateQuestionsSmsStatus?smsProfileId=' + smsProfileId + '&active=' + active
    }).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          return data;
      })
      ...
```

and, to accommodate that, your controller's `updateQuestionsSmsStatus` function should adjust the callback:

```
$scope.updateQuestionsSmsStatus = function () {
  questionSelectionService.UpdateQuestionsSmsStatus($scope.smsProfile.Id, !$scope.smsProfile.Active).then(function (data) {
      $scope.smsProfile.Active = (data.result == "success") ? data.active : !data.active;
    }
   );
 };
```